# Replace matching class from javascript var before append for dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace matching class from javascript var before appending  dynamically-generated content. It will match one id out of all ids in this variable and for that id we will replace hideeee class. I know it can be done easily with

```js
document.getElementById("testid").classList.remove('hideeee');
```

but it requires that ID to be available in DOM. In our case we are trying to insert these data and show only one row which matches the clicked id.

When those buttons are clicked it sends the ID of the clicked button and we know that and we capture with `event.target.id`. Here in content var we have just added extra y to differentiate those ID to original clicked buttons
and by default `.hideeee` class is `display:none` so we want to remove `.hideeee` class when ID matches `showthisclass` var before appending in last line

```js
function showpdfaq1() {
    consol e.log(event.target.id);
    var showthisclass = event.target.id+'y';

    let heading = `<div class="css-17bb5rx backtohome" style="flex-direction: row; align-items: center;">
        <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" color="#ebebeb" height="30" width="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="color: rgb(235, 235, 235); cursor: pointer; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 4px; margin-left: -8px;"><path d="M217.9 256L345 129c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6 0-33.9-9.4-9.4-24.6-9.3-34 0L167 239c-9.1 9.1-9.3 23.7-.7 33.1L310.9 417c4.7 4.7 10.9 7 17 7s12.3-2.3 17-7c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6 0-33.9L217.9 256z"></path></svg>
            <h1 class="bigheadd">Read Help Articles</h1>
            </div>`

    let content = `<div class="css-1iyoj2o" style="padding: 20px; margin-top: -42px; margin-bottom: 42px;">
        <div class="ant-card ant-card-small hideeee" id="faq-1y" style="box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 10px; border-radius: 4px; margin-top: 20px;"><div class="ant-card-body" style="padding: 20px;"><div direction="row" class="css-o2j9ze" style="align-items: center;"><h3 class="bigheadd style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 16px;">How to Return My Order</h3></div><div direction="row" class="css-o2j9ze" style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 14px;"><div class="css-iittdj"><div>Since all our items are food items, we do not allow a return of the same.<br>In case the product got damaged in transit, Please record a video and Contact Us within 24hrs of Delivery.<br><br></div></div></div></div></div>
            
            <div class="ant-card ant-card-small hideeee" id="faq-2y" style="box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 10px; border-radius: 4px; margin-top: 20px;"><div class="ant-card-body" style="padding: 20px;"><div direction="row" class="css-o2j9ze" style="align-items: center;"><h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 16px;">How to Return My Order</h3></div><div direction="row" class="css-o2j9ze" style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 14px;"><div class="css-iittdj"><div>Since all our items are food items, we do not allow a return of the same.<br>In case the product got damaged in transit, Please record a video and Contact Us within 24hrs of Delivery.<br><br></div></div></div></div></div>
            
            <div class="ant-card ant-card-small hideeee" id="faq-3y" style="box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 10px; border-radius: 4px; margin-top: 20px;"><div class="ant-card-body" style="padding: 20px;"><div direction="row" class="css-o2j9ze" style="align-items: center;"><h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 16px;">How to get reward</h3></div><div direction="row" class="css-o2j9ze" style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 14px;"><div class="css-iittdj"><div>for every spend you will get rewRD HERE <br><br></div></div></div></div></div>

            
            
        <h3 class="bigheadd>Did this answer your question?</h3>
        <div class="css-0" style="margin-top: 10px;"><button onclick="message()" type="button" class="ant-btn"><span>No, I need help</span></button></div>
        </div>`
            
    var finalcontkke =  document.getElementById(showthisclass).classList.remove(hideeee);

    document.getElementById("appnewchat5").innerHTML = gethtml(heading, content);
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the variable `showthisclass` - when you are then using it as parameter for `getElementById`? _"but it requires html that id to be available in DOM"_ - so work on it _after_ you inserted it into the DOM then? If all you do is removing a class, that should not make too much of a difference to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe this html wll be inserted when customer clicks of faq title. so we are trying to show only one that customer clicked by removing the hideeeee class from that div

Comment: Then hide the others immediately after you added the HTML to the document. As long as you do this directly after, the browser will not update the display before your JS code is done anyway.

Comment: @CBroe thx for ur idea , i think that i best. i will add one function just after innerHTML to  remove class from that partular id but i doubt it may give error sometime because javascript is just appended

Comment: @CBroe solved with ur idea. can  u plz give that idea in answer i can accept. that idea did not triggered me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it requires html that id to be available in DOM

You can put it into the DOM first, and then replace the classes in the DOM, using DOM methods.

As long as your JS code does not get "interrupted", the browser will not update the display - so you can insert this first, replace your classes, and then when your JS is done with both of those, the browser will update the display to show the result.

An alternative would be to use a DOM Parser first (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) - but that should not really be necessary here in this situation.